# Integrating Amazon SES with Sendmail to EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I am trying to integrate SES with Sendmail in My EC2 Server.

I looked this documents and followed steps, but didn't work out.
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.MTAs.Sendmail.html

I hoped to see video, but there wasn't anything about this one.
I couldn't even find a good article or blog about this.

Can you help me out? I just need to set up Sendmail via SSH.

Comment: sendmail command didn't work out through SES, therefore, I couldn't get mails from server

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible -- log into your AWS Console, to the SES Dashboard, and you'll see a section titled "SMTP Settings" on the lefthand nav. There you will find instructions and a mechanism to create your own SMTP credentials.

At that point you will need to set up your Postfix or Sendmail to act as a relay for outbound mail, redirecting it to the AWS SES Service API.

*HOWEVER* a few caveats:

- You won't be able to use this as some normal SMTP gateway or outbound mail host unless you were to verify any possible sender for mail headed out of your instance. A more ideal case for this is a vendor who sends out large marketing mails to its customers, or a service that pushes out mail on a subscription or alert basis, all of which come from just one or a small handful of addresses.
- Also, using SES means you'll have to live by AWS's thresholds, even once you've requested production access. An AWS engineer told me in training that they generally keep an eye on your mailflow and any bounces or rejects, as well as complaints made about your mail, and so long as things look good they will continue to throttle you up in that regard.

Good luck to you.